# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity Android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am trying to get the device bluetooth address so when ever I click on send

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        DeviceListActivity.class), GET_DEVICE_TO_SEND);
```

file via bluetooth the Discovery starts when its done I select one of founded devices

at the `onActivityResult` 
I have these code

```
if (requestCode == GET_DEVICE_TO_SEND && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
String device = data
.getStringExtra(DeviceListActivity.DEVICE_ADDRESS);
String name = data.getStringExtra(DeviceListActivity.DEVICE_NAME);
```

the function `onActivityResult`  is called and then the application stopp

The class: `MainUI` contains the Tabhost .

the class :`FilesUI`  is where the function `onActivityResult` is located

The log

```
03-19 18:39:28.858: E/AndroidRuntime(22817): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.Connect/com.android.Connect.UI.MainUI}: java.lang.RuntimeException:`enter code here` Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=Files, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.android.Connect/com.android.Connect.UI.MainUI}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Are you sure `data` isn't null?

Comment: please try to check whether data is null or not

Comment: I think the problem is here 
   String msg = "file," + fileToSend.getName() + ","
     + readFileAsString(fileToSend.getPath());
   Log.d(TAG, "the file " + msg);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem is here

```
  String msg = "file," + fileToSend.getName() + "," + readFileAsString(fileToSend.getPath()); Log.d(TAG, "the file " + msg);
```